# NSTimer fire problem(not the common invalidate issue)

Tags: iphone, nstimer

my code as below:

```
- ( void ) restart {
    [ self pause ];
    //init something here...
    [ self proceed ];
}

- ( void ) pause {
    if ( [ _timer isValid ] ) {
        [ _timer invalidate ];
        _timer = nil;
    }
}

- ( void ) proceed {
    _timer = [ NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1 target: self selector: @selector ( fireHandler ) userInfo: nil repeats: YES ];
}
```

Mostly it works fine, but I found that in some case, after I invoked the method "restart" more than one time, sometimes, the fireHandler had been invoked more than one time within a single timeInterval(or the timeInterval was become shorter, anyway, it runs faster suddenly).

Now I add the sender to the fireHandler, and use NSLog to check the memory address, I found something as below:

<_*NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<*_NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<_*NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<*_NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<_*NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<*_NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>

and repeat... It means that it is always the same timer.
But sometimes when I call "restart" again, it indicates

<_*NSCFTimer: 0x4e3d740>
<*_NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<_*NSCFTimer: 0x4e3d740>
<*_NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<_*NSCFTimer: 0x4e3d740>
<*_NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>...repeats

It means there are two timer, it seems that the first one has not been invalidate and release on time. It runs with the second one at the same time, and some seconds later, after the second one has be removed, even that the first one still alive!

It will appear again after a while. Such situation is not very often, without rules, it happens about 30% of the whole time. I have not any idea about this....Please if anyone can give me some idea to get the exactly problem, at least.

Comment: Make sure you are calling `restart` from the same thread each time.

Answer (score 1):

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval]` creates and schedules a new timer each time you call it. So when you call `proceed` several times, the system creates and starts a new timer each time, overriding your `_timer` reference and creating leaks.

I can't say why you get the behavior to describe, but accidentally calling `proceed` several times could be the cause. Consider rewriting it like this instead and see if that helps:

```
- (void)proceed 
{
    [_timer invalidate];
    _timer = [NSTimer schedule...];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, in this case, I never call "proceed" directly, every time I call "restart" instead. So, it already process the invalidate with the method "pause". Now I add the sender to the fireHandler, and use NSLog to check the memory address, I found something as below:

Comment: <__NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
and repeat... It means that it is always the same timer.

Comment: But sometimes when I call "restart" again, <__NSCFTimer: 0x4e3d740>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e3d740>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e3d740>
<__NSCFTimer: 0x4e610a0>... it means there are two timer, it seems that the first one has not been invalidate and release on time. And runs with the second one at the same time, and after a while, it disapper...

Comment: And even that it will appear again after a while. Such situation is not very often, without rules, it happens about 30% of the whole time. I have not any idea about this....Please if anyone can give me some idea to get the exactly problem, at least.